# C++ - Convert vector<uint64> to a single number

Tags: c++, c++17

There is a method to convert a `std::vector<uint64>` to a single number?

I have a vector like this:

```
v[0] = 0;
v[1] = 6796890219657246832;
```

Or like this:

```
v[0] = 16377;
v[1] = 2631694347470643681;
v[2] = 11730294873282192384;
```

The result I like to get is, in the first case `6796890219657246832` and in the second: `16377263169434747064368111730294873282192384`. My main problem is choosing the data type for the value as it is possible that the vector size is not always 2 but it could be 5 or higher.

Comment: I think you need to using [GMP](https://gmplib.org) and a wrapper on `std::vector<mpz_t>`.

Comment: Perhaps a `std::string` would be ok? `std::string res; for(auto val : v) res += std::to_string(val);`

Comment: You will have to use some big math library or create one yourself to store larger sized integers.

Comment: No primitive data type is large enough to hold such large numbers. If you want, you could store it inside a string. If you want to do arithmetic with it, you could look at some [arbitrary precision-libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C%2B%2B_multiple_precision_arithmetic_libraries) on the net.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to combine elements of vector in one variable?

Comment: The type you'll need will either be a built-in integral type that is 320 bits or more (I'm not aware of any implementations that support such a type natively) or a big integer library.    If all you're trying to do is output the resultant value (e.g. write out a `std::string` containing `"16377263169434747064368111730294873282192384"`) it's not overly difficult to write code to achieve that (albeit not as simply as just streaming some integral type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No C++ provided types will support that many digits. So obviously, you need BIG-INT for that. Ethier implemented by yourself or using a tested library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

For example, using GMP will be like:

```cpp
static mpz_class convert_to_i(std::vector<std::size_t> const& vec)
{
        std::string sum;
        for (auto const number : vec) {
                sum += std::to_string(number);
        }
        return mpz_class(sum);
}
```

Let the `vec` be:

```cpp
std::vector<std::size_t> const vec = {
        16377,
        2631694347470643681,
        1173029487328219238
};
```

Result of `convert_to_i(vec)` will be:

```cpp
1637726316943474706436811173029487328219238
```

If your original numbers are also big-int:

```cpp
static mpz_class convert_to_i(std::vector<mpz_class> const& vec)
{
        std::string sum;
        for (auto const& number : vec) {
                sum += number.get_str();
        }
        return mpz_class(sum);
}
```

Let the `vec_2` be:

```cpp
std::vector<mpz_class> const vec_2 = {
        mpz_class("26316943474706436812631694347470643681"),
        mpz_class("263169434747064368126316943474706436812631694347470643681")
};
```

Result of `convert_to_i(vec_2)` will be:

```cpp
26316943474706436812631694347470643681263169434747064368126316943474706436812631694347470643681
```

---

Just for copy/paste and test: [the code](https://github.com/another-ghasem/examples/blob/master/sub_examples/vector_to_number_i/source/main.cpp#L52).

Comment: To me the examples look like OP doesn't want to multiply numbers but concatenate them into a big string/number.

Comment: @ypnos, I'm sorry, the answer was edited.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani I try toicompile it but it doesn't work

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man, For using GMP, you must link it to your program either by a Build System or directly using the compiler command-line options. Check out the GMP documents.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani If you wold you help me, here there is my answere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977106/cmake-link-library-included-into-the-project

As you can see, I include the gmp `lib` and `include` in my project and link them via `cmake` (like your example)

Answer (score 1):

The [Boost.Multiprecision library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) can be used for computations with very large numbers. This will do what you want using that library:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

mp::cpp_int add_numbers(const std::vector<uint64_t> &numbers)
{
    mp::cpp_int sum = 0;
    size_t digits = 0;
    
    for (std::vector<uint64_t>::const_reverse_iterator it = numbers.crbegin(); it != numbers.crend(); ++it)
    {
        mp::cpp_int num(*it);
        sum += num * mp::pow(mp::cpp_int(10), digits);
        digits += num.str().size();
    }
    
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<uint64_t> numbers = {16377U, 2631694347470643681U, 11730294873282192384U};
    mp::cpp_int sum = add_numbers(numbers);
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
16377263169434747064368111730294873282192384
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83d4123ad3a4752e)

Answer (score 0):

use `std::accumulate` and generate a string.

```
std::string result = std::accumulate (
         v.begin(),
         v.end(),
         std::string(),
         [](const std::string &result, const uint64 &val) {
             return result + std::to_string(val); }
         );
```