# CMake - Link library included into the project

Tags: c++, cmake, gmp

I'm trying to include the `GMP` library into my project.
This is my folder tree:
[image]

As you can see, the `gmp` folder (that contains include and lib) is into the `include` folder.

This is my `app/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

add_executable(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ../include/KMC/kmc_api/kmc_file.cpp
  ../include/KMC/kmc_api/kmer_api.cpp
  ../include/KMC/kmc_api/mmer.cpp
  main.cpp
)

include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/gmp/lib
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  gmp
  gmpxx
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/gmp/include
)

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE DEBUG=1)
```

and this, is the `CMakeLists.txt` in the project root:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/g++")

project(MyProj)
enable_language(CXX)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR 1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -fopenmp")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
include(CMakeToolsHelpers OPTIONAL)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(include/KMC)

add_subdirectory(app)
```

After, `cd build && cmake ..` I run `make -j12` and than, -the compilation fail:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable DynaDBG
cd /Users/th3g3ntl3man/Desktop/Repository/DynaDBG/build/app && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.4/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/DynaDBG.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/local/bin/g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -fopenmp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/DynaDBG.dir/__/include/KMC/kmc_api/kmc_file.cpp.o CMakeFiles/DynaDBG.dir/__/include/KMC/kmc_api/kmer_api.cpp.o CMakeFiles/DynaDBG.dir/__/include/KMC/kmc_api/mmer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/DynaDBG.dir/main.cpp.o -o DynaDBG   -L/Users/th3g3ntl3man/Desktop/Repository/DynaDBG/include/gmp/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/Users/th3g3ntl3man/Desktop/Repository/DynaDBG/include/gmp/lib -lgmp -lgmpxx 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZlsRSoPK12__mpz_struct", referenced from:
      __ZlsIA1_12__mpz_structS1_ERSoS2_RK10__gmp_exprIT_T0_E in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [app/CMakeFiles/DynaDBG.dir/build.make:151: app/DynaDBG] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/th3g3ntl3man/Desktop/Repository/DynaDBG/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:116: app/CMakeFiles/DynaDBG.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/th3g3ntl3man/Desktop/Repository/DynaDBG/build'
make: *** [Makefile:106: all] Error 2
```

UPDATE:
Compiling the [example](https://github.com/another-ghasem/examples/tree/master/sub_examples/vector_to_number_i) I have this error:
[image]

Comment: Was gmpxx compiled with the same standard library?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I install `gmp` via `brew`

Comment: I think brew uses clang by default? Anyway, in the link line, somehow there is `-lgmp` but no `-lgmpxx`...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Sorry Sorry, I update my answer. `-gmpxx` was missing because in the `app/CMakeLists.txt` line 20 was missing `gmpxx` after `gmp`

Comment: Why not `find_package(GMP REQUIRED)`?

Comment: @CoryKramer Because if I try to use `find_package()` I have this error `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):By not providing "Findgmp.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "gmp", but
CMake did not find one.`